# Space complexity of global minimum cut

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, space-complexity, max-flow-min-cut

Are there any non-trivial bounds on the space complexity of global minimum cut? The problem is known to be in $\mathsf{RNC}$. Is anything known about containment in either $\mathsf{L}$ or $\mathsf{NL}$?

Such a bound seems unlikely for the space-complexity of s-t minimum cut given that maximum flow is $\mathsf{P}$-complete.

Comment: Is global mincut in NC? I think it is only known to be in RNC. Look in Karger's paper https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=331608.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely correct (updated to RNC in the original post). I don't know of any NC algorithms for global min cut. The fastest deterministic sequential algorithm seems to be due to Kawarabayashi and Thorup (https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2746588).